# <identifier> expected Java compile time error with add method on HashSet

Tags: java, compiler-errors, hashset

I have looked but can't find anything exactly like this.

I am trying to create a set of integers and I need to add "2" to it initially.

```
private static HashSet<Integer> pSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

pSet.add(new Integer(2));

          ^
```

For some reason this is giving me a compile time error that an identifier is expected where I have indicated.

What is causing this and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All code needs to be inside a method or initializer. You can add a value to `pSet` through a static initialization block:

```
private static HashSet<Integer> pSet = new HashSet<Integer>();

static {
    pSet.add(new Integer(2));
}
```

Also, boxing `2` is unnecessary, `pSet.add(2)` will work just fine.

Comment: Thanks! This was my problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to initialise `pSet` with an initial value directly, you can simply do:

```
private static Set<Integer> pSet = new HashSet<Integer>(Arrays.asList(2));
```